# Forward connections from docker container on specific port to local interface on host

Tags: iptables, ssh-tunnel, docker

I am attempting to run services in containers within a cloud provider. I would like the containerised applications to authenticate with an on-premises LDAP server, which is (currently) available via an SSH tunnel out to the cloud. The tunnel is available on the docker host machine on `127.0.0.1:6636`.

Is it possible to get the containers to access `127.0.0.1:6636` on the host machine, e.g. through some kind of proxy or iptables configuration?

I can get the tunnel to work if I set `GatewayPorts=yes` in the host's `sshd_config` and use `docker run --add-host` to add the host's `docker0` IP into `/etc/hosts` in the container , but that means that the tunnel is available on all interfaces. I can presumably lock down access to the tunnel to the `docker0` interface, but I'd rather the tunnel was only on the loopback interface.

I don't want use `--net=host`, because I want to be able to use container linking.

```
Cloud                    |
                         |
+------------------+     |      +--------+     +----------+
| Host      Tunnel |     |      | Tunnel |     |   Tunnel |
|                O-------------------------------O Target |
| +-----------+  | |     |      |  Host  |     +----------+
| | Container |--+ |     |      +--------+
| +-----------+    |     |
+------------------+     |      Premises
                         |
```

Comment: How about running the tunnel inside a container and linking to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in the IP of your host's docker0 interface as an environment variable and connect to the LDAP Server. As an example, on the host:

```
$ ip addr show docker0
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.1.42.1/16 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 fe80::60e4:ffff:fe97:1308/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
$ DOCKERADDR=$(ip addr show docker0 | grep inet\ | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1)
$ docker run -it -e DOCKERADDR=${DOCKERADDR} image
```

On the inside of the container you can connect to ${DOCKERADDR}:6636

note: on coreos you already have these variables in your environment if you `. /etc/environment`: `COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4` and `COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4`